# TextMate 2 , LaTex : preview in Skim

Tags: viewers, textmate

I have tried to configure TextMate 2 in order to typeset and view latex files. I have configured the bundle preferences as in this figure

[image]

but I only manage to typeset the file and eventually view it within TextMate: after the compilation, nothing happens (no error, no visualization of the pdf).

As far as I have understood, Skim is recommended for jumping from the pdf to the LaTex source and viceversa.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is the `.pdf` file created? Can you view it? Is the problem to do with getting a viewer to open the file automatically when you compile?

Comment: The pdf is created, but the file is not opened automatically. If I open the file manually, jumping from the pdf to the source is not possible.

Comment: So the problem you are having is getting the pdf to open automatically and getting reverse search to work. I'd recommend editing the question to make it clearer.